# Javascript + Modify string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What would be the quickest way to remove "everything" from a string, starting from the first "dot".

For example:

```
This.Is.A.Test
```

=> would become

```
This
```

Comment: For future benchmarking purposes, may I refer you to [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/)?

Comment: Regex is unnecessary for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function like this:

```
"This.Is.A.Test".split(".")[0]; // will work even if there are no dots
```

Or you could use the `substr()` function in combination with the `indexOf()` function, like this:

```
var myStr = "This.Is.A.Test";
var justTheFirstBit = myStr.substr(0, myStr.indexOf(".")); // needs 1 dot minimum
```

Comment: Fixed your `substring` function for you.

Comment: @mc10: `substr` is just as valid as `substring`. I'll be changing it back, although I appreciate the edit. :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville - Too long, `"This.Is.A.Test".replace(/\..+$/,"");` is better.

Comment: @GGG: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) says nothing about `substr()` being frowned upon.

Comment: @Derek Regex is usually slower than string manipulation, and string manipulation is easier to understand. Regardless, it's the same length (one line), so I don't see your point.

Comment: @Derek: That's shorter than my second example, but my first example is shorter than that and *far* more readable. :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville - This will not work of there are no dots in the text.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville it's because of discrepancies with negative offsets or missing parameters or something between Everyone's Favorite Browser(TM) and other browsers. Or something. Might be ancient history now though.

Comment: @Derek: My first example will work if there are no dots. [Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyJavascript/pep2E/).

Comment: second suggestion will not work if string contains no dots (indexOf returns -1). See my answer.

Comment: @Derek: I've run a jsPerf on this before and `split()` is faster IIRC.

Comment: @mc10: substring() and substr() are two very different functions.  `substring(a,b)` returns the characters from `a` to `b` whereas `substr(a,b)` returns `b` number of characters, starting at `a`

Comment: @PitaJ Of course they are. I just found that `substring()` makes more sense to me in this case.

Comment: @mc10 just making sure you knew

Comment: @ElliotBonneville [here's some info](http://www.haroldbakker.com/substr.php) about the weird IE `substr` behavior. It only affects negative offsets. `substring` is also standardized in ES, while `substr` is not. So occasionally you'll run into people who dislike `substr`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
var string = "This.Is.A.Test";
var newstring = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("."));
```

Comment: @PenchoIlchev I'm assuming the OP's input text has a dot in it, based on his/her question. If necessary, you could always check if the dot existed or not.

Answer (score 0):

### ***[MDN - replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)***

---

You can use the the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function like this:

```
"This.Is.A.Test".replace(/\..+$/,"");
```

This is the regular expression you need:

```
/\..+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should have complexity of O(2n) and should ever search up to the first dot (twice).

```
​var a = "This.Is.String";
var ind = a.indexOf(".");
ind = ind == -1 ? a.length : ind;
​var b = a.substring(0, ind);
​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#el').text( $('#el').text().split('.')[0] );
```

### *[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ujaxoq/edit#javascript,html,live)*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split